# How to resize div size proportional with browser size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

***JQuery***

```
    $(window).ready(function(){

    var w = $(window).width();//to detect the width of the browser
    var h = $(window).height();//to detect the height of the browser

    $(window).resize(function(){

        var w = $(window).width();//new width of the browser
        var h = $(window).height();//new height of the browser

        $("#left").css('height'+ h 'px.');//this is where I'm not sure how to assign height      value according to the browser size.

    });  

    });
```

***My css***

```
   #main
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
}
#left
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #666666;

}
#right
{
    width:80%;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    background: #ff9900;
}
```

***My Html***

```
   <div id="main">
        <div id="left">
        </div>

        <div id="right">
        </div>

    </div>
```

Now the problem is the height of left and right DIV.
if I set the height:100%; it follows the content height ,which I don't want .
I want the height stretched down to fit the browser height.
So if I use, height:650px; it works but how if the page resized to smaller or bigger size?
How to detect the size of the browser the page being viewed and proportionally change the height so that there won't be scrollbar?

Comment: it was default mechanism of a div.. no need to write anything for this

Comment: it's better to use javascript here.......
use screen.height and screen.width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your trying to make the div the full length of the browser window. If so, using something like `div {height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }` wont work if you have other divs in the way.

Try this:

```
div { 

position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom: 0;

}
```

that will make your div the height of the entire browser even with the rest of your site in the way.

example in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5MUTy/1/

Comment: a position should be absolute here?

Comment: Try changing absolute in the fiddle. If you do so the height wont take up the entire screen.

Comment: It seems strange I know. I was doing this last week and ran into this problem using absolute myslef, and had to ask the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021706/popup-div-to-fill-entire-browser-width-and-height . The answer was to set it to fixed.

Comment: with "fixed" you can't scroll down to access content at bottom of page,if page height is more than screen height

Comment: @Arun the whole point of this answer is to set div height = page height. You do so by specifying top, left, right, and bottom. That would never be an issue.

Comment: yes specifying top, left, right, and bottom will do that, but fixing content is not solution

Comment: it is. check the fiddle I provided and check this question as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021706/popup-div-to-fill-entire-browser-width-and-height . Please feel free to give your own answer.

Comment: The div is the height of the rendered home page.  Including all of the elements.  You would be able to scroll down in the full view mode of the fiddle if the content is greater than the view able area.  In the fiddle currently, the div encompasses all elements,  so scrolling is impossible if there's nothing  to scroll too. This is a trick for grey masks of newsletter pop-ups.  Check one such pop-up out at remodo.com.  You'll be able to scroll :-)

Answer (score 1):

It was default mechanism of a div.. no need to write anything for this
just put margin and padding to zero for both `<body>` and `<div>`.

Or If you are interested in jquery or javascript.. 
Then you can do it better by using

`$(window).innerWidth()` and 
`$(window).innerHeight()` 
//Above code returns the viewport area of the browser

methods in-spite of using

`$(window).width()` and 
`$(window).height()`.
//This code returns the entire browser width and height.

Comment: Thanks @Lakshmi!  Is there nothing can be done to fit the div height according to the browser height? All my jquery doesn't work .so stick to fix the height in px instead of %. But I'm worried if the page viewed in larger screen. The body colour will be shown in the empty space right?

Answer (score 1):

Here this seems to work better for me. Although calc() is not that widely supported by browsers but you could still you static height in %.

http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/BlpeK

Use with css reset and adjust your margins accordingly and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the css document or within style tags,

```
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
div{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is correct syntax to add CSS in div through jQuery.

```
$("#left").css('height', h +'px'); // where h is height variable.
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can you tell me how to detect the browser size and display it on browser?

Comment: You did that in your code. Below is browser width and height which you can get on resize.
var w = $(window).width();//new width of the browser
var h = $(window).height();//new height of the browser

Please note: innerwidth() will not work with window. you can refer jQuery docs. http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that,
to make a DIV fit to the bottom of a page just need to add postion:absolute.
but since I'm having two DIVs ,one on left and another on the right,
I add postion:fixed to the left DIV and postion :relative ,float:right to the right DIV.
prior to that I added DIV{position:fixed}, then only it worked in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE10.
So I added height:100% to the DIV tag..now it works in all browsers..

Thanks for all for sharing your thoughts.Bytheway I didn't use any jquery so far  only css!